# How to multiply a cell by 100 and copy the resulting value into the last column of another sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Having trouble with very simple code, I have successfully copied cells and ranges of cells to other sheets, but I cannot get the multiplication of a value to copy, I am sure this is very simple so apologize up front.

The error I get is "TypeError: Cannot find function getcopyTo in objec"

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[1];
var nextsheet = ss.getSheets()[4];
var lastColumn = nextsheet.getLastColumn()+1;
var newData = sheet.getRange("D35").getValue()*100;
newData.getcopyTo(nextsheet.getRange(9,lastcolumn), {contentsOnly:true});
```

Comment: Hello, is stacktrace the same as the stackdriver error reporting?  For some reason I do not have access to this but am looking into it.

Answer (score 1):

```
var newData = sheet.getRange("D35").getValue()*100;
```

This returns a number, like 4200. Then you try `newData.getcopyTo` which can't possibly work, there is no method "getcopyTo" in the number 4200. (Actually, there is no such method in Apps Script, it looks like some mix of getValues and copyTo). What you should do is

```
nextsheet.getRange(9,lastcolumn).setValue(newData);
```

The method `copyTo` is used in the form `sourceRange.copyTo(targetRange)` but that's direct copying from one range to another, without any manipulation like multiplying by 100.